# Do I have the latest firmware update for my Time Capsule? How can I force an upgrade of the firmware?

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule, firmware

[image]

I am running the latest Maverick. Does anyone know how can I force an upgrade of my firmware?

Answer (score 2):

If AirPort Utility doesn't prompt you that an update is available, then you have the latest version installed on the Time Capsule.

> **How do I know when an update is available?**
>
> - AirPort Utility automatically checks for updates once a week (even if it's not open), then notifies you if an update is available.
> - When you open AirPort Utility, it will check for updates and display a badge by the name of any AirPort device in your network that has an available firmware update.

<sup>Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1218</sup>

Comment: Thanks George, but it looks I don't have the latest version running for some odd reason. Can you confirm that from my screenshot? I have the option to check updates automatically selected.

Comment: @Sergio It depends on the model of Time Capsule you have. The latest 7.7.3 update requires the [new Time Capsules with 802.11ac (June 2013)](http://support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/DL1708/AirPortBaseStation.png) which looks different to the one in the icon shown in your screenshot, but I'm not certain as I don't have a Time Capsule myself.

Answer (score 0):

The Airport Utility.app and the Time Capsule utilize separate application and firmware versions.

Airport Utlility.app is updated via Software Update on your Mac.  As **grgarside** mentioned above, when you launch Airport Utility.app and connect to a Airport Extreme, Airport Express, or Time Capsule, it automatically checks to see if it is running the latest firmware.  Based on your screenshot, you have an Airport Time Capsule with 802.11n.  I'd look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPort_Time_Capsule#Comparison_chart) to determine your specific marketing model number.  From there, I'd Google " firmware" to clarify, however I'm almost positive your Time Capsule is on the latest firmware.